# Circular diffraction onto uneven surface

Tags: optics, diffraction

I'm trying to figure out how to solve for a surface using a circular diffraction.

I have a pinhole diffraction that I'm projecting into a surface and I'm trying to figure out how to derive the shape of the surface using the airy pattern.

I understand the Fresnel-Kirchoff equations and the intensity equation using the bessel function of the first kind, but I'm confused at where to start when trying to solve these on an uneven surface.

Comment: So you want to solve the near-field (Fresnell) pattern for each "depth" on the uneven surface?  If that's what you're after, I think you're just going to have to crunch the equations for each level.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talbot_effect, for example.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't see that this is necessarily near-field, but your idea is undoubtedly correct.  It the OP can add more details about what he's after, it would help.

Comment: Well the end goal is that I want to map a 3d surface and have the range to the object.